# Is there a way to get a base class name in C++ at runtime?

Tags: c++, inheritance, runtime, classname

You can get the current class name, assuming RTTI is enabled, using typeid(this).name() at runtime.

I would like to be able to get the name of the base class for "this". Is that possible? I'm not using multiple inheritance, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: Why do you need that?  Usually when you find yourself needing RTTI, that is a sign of a design issue.

Comment: The reason I wanted this was to provide debug output using an existing call in the framework of a legacy system. The classname and base classname are available in the code, but there are about 300 classes involved, so I was looking for something I could use in one global search and replace. This is for a customer request; I would have solved that problem in a completely different way, but constraints of binary compatibility with legacy software prevent my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Plus, I don't think that you can count on `typeid(this).name()` to give you a class name (AFAIK the exact value to be returned is implementation-defined).

Answer (score 1):

No sir. Sorry. And your method of getting the class name this way is implementation-dependent. On my implementation, I get the mangled name.

Answer (score 1):

The information can't reliably be retrieved because it isn't reliably stored anywhere, in turn because the C++ philosophy is not to give you things unless you explicitly ask for them.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not, and the reason you need this feature is dubious :)

Comment: come on, there may be obscure use cases for what OP wants to achieve.

Comment: The reason I wanted this was to provide debug output using an existing call in the framework of a legacy system. The classname and base classname are available in the code, but there are about 300 classes involved, so I was looking for something I could use in one global search and replace.